# Order By Asc and Desc both in single query

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a query which retrieves latest data from table with pagination which is working fine.

But once the data is older from current time it should also appear but after the latest one.

```
SELECT A.UserId,A.FirstName,A.LastName,A.PostDate
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(M.PostDate AS DATETIMEOFFSET) DESC) AS 'RowNumber'
    M.UserId,
   M.FirstName,
            M.LastName,
    M.PostDate
    FROM Messages AS M
   Where M.PostDate >= GetDate()
) A
       WHERE A.RowNumber BETWEEN @RowStart AND @RowEnd 
 ORDER BY CAST(A.PostDate AS DATETIMEOFFSET)  DESC
```

Comment: You probably should add an example of the data and expected output

Comment: For e.g. current time is 12  PM and i display messages first greater than 12 PM (Current Time) and if there are no enough messages then i display messages less than 12 PM (CurrentTime)

Comment: @user1037747 Then You Cant If you specify you will get error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm exactly getting what you're looking for, but this should get you something close. I created a CTE with two computed columns:

- BeforeAfter, which determines if the date happens before or after the passed in date
- AbsDiff, which gives the absolute value of the date diff.

Then, I just sort using those two fields:

```
DECLARE @current datetime = GETDATE()
;WITH cteMessages AS 
(
    SELECT UserId, FirstName, LastName, PostDate, 
    CASE WHEN PostDate < @current THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BeforeAfter,
    ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @current, PostDate)) AS AbsDiff
    FROM Messages
)
SELECT * FROM cteMessages
ORDER BY BeforeAfter, AbsDiff
```

From those results, you can see how they are sorted first by messages newer than the passed in date, then in reverse order from older messages. You can substitute that order by into your Row_Number function.

Answer (score 2):

You cant do `Order By ASC` and `DESC` on the Same column of a Table if you do you will get the following Error

> Msg 169, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 A column has been specified more
>   than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be
>   unique.

If you want it you may do using Join of the same Table and order by the same column like

```
SELECT A.UserId,A.FirstName,A.LastName,A.PostDate
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(M.PostDate AS DATETIMEOFFSET) DESC) AS 'RowNumber'
   M.UserId,
   M.FirstName,
   M.LastName,
   M.PostDate
    FROM Messages AS M
   Where M.PostDate >= GetDate()
) A
 Inner Join Messages AS Msg on Msg.UserId=A.UserId
WHERE A.RowNumber BETWEEN @RowStart AND @RowEnd 
ORDER BY CAST(A.PostDate AS DATETIMEOFFSET) DESC,
         CAST(Msg.PostDate AS DATETIMEOFFSET)  ASC
```

Comment: It is giving duplicates.. Also expected output is not appearing

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the following line

```
Where M.PostDate >= GetDate()
```